# Getting past checkins of an authenticated user in Google latitude API via JSON

Tags: java, google-api, google-latitude

I cross-posted this to the latitude-api google group but there doesn't seem to be alot of activity around there so here it goes:

is there a way to use the latitude api to GET the recent checkins of 
an authenticated user? I fiddled around with the latitude-api examples in Java but no avail.

Just to be clear: I would like to get a 
JSON response that includes the name and the time of past checkins. I 
couldn't find any reference to this in the places api nor in the 
latitude api. 
Would I have to somehow manually assign a place to a lat/long 
response? However that would still not give me the actual status of 
the user (checked in or not).

Any pointers?

Cheers, 
Vincent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alright, I managed to solve this:

The Android Latitude checkins do not get handled by the latitude api or the places api but by the Google Buzz api. So [this](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html#search-places) would be the right place to start looking.

Comment: The link in this answer is no longer active.